# Does Odata client libraray support nested And/Or operators?

Tags: linq, nested, odata

I am using Odata client lib 7.20.0 and I have code like below

`var queryForFilter = container.Docs.Where(d =>(d.SourceType == "A" && d.ApplicationName == "all") || (d.SourceType == "C" && d.ApplicationName == "app"));`

I found it generates a query with filter like below,

`$filter=SourceType eq 'A' and ApplicationName eq 'all' or SourceType eq 'C' and ApplicationName eq 'app'`

It doesn't know adding () for the subqueries, so the filter is invalid.  Is there any workaround?  Or it is unsupported for such nested And/Or operators?

I also tried Union without using ||,  but I got error saying Union is not supported

Comment: Actually generated query is correct, check [Operator Precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-odata/f3380585-3f87-41d9-a2dc-ff46cc38e7a6). For your case, brackets are not needed.